# Is there a way to disable auto-update without re-running the installer?

Tags: install4j

We have an installer with a separately selectable auto-update feature.
Normally, if a customer wants to switch that feature on or off after the installation has completed, we tell them to re-run the installer and correct the setting. (Tested, works.)
Now a customer has a problem: Their corporate IT prepared an installation package that (mistakenly) has auto-update installed, and said IT refuses to put out a corrected installation package.

So the question is:
Can I give the customer a reasonably future-safe way to disable auto-update - say, by modifying a registry entry - without having to re-run the installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, the registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ej-technologies\install4j\installations
```

contains values with the names `updateSchedule<application id>`. If you locate the one for your installer, you can change the value data to "never".

Comment: Thanks, that's going to solve it. I'll mark the answer as accepted as soon as I get feedback.